# Set authorization header param in interceptor.module.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, http, header

I need to send an authorization token into every request's header and I can't find a proper way to set params into intercepetor.module.ts code.

Here's an extract from my Angular interceptor.module.ts

```
intercept(
        req: HttpRequest<any>,
        next: HttpHandler,
    ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        console.warn("Loader Started - HTTP request: " + req.url);

        let dupReq = req.clone({
            setHeaders:{
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
                'Accept'       : 'application/json',
                'Authorization': "Basic "+ myToken
            }
        });

        return next.handle(dupReq).pipe(
            map(event => {
                return event;
            }),
            catchError(error => {
                return Observable.throw(error);
            }),
            finalize(() => {

            })
        );
    }
```

When I go into Chrome's Network tab in debug mode, request's header had no change and it is not showing the 'authorization' param.

I've tried to set the headers thru `headers.append()` method and it had no difference as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const dupReq = req.clone({
    setHeaders: {
      Authorization: "Basic "+ btoa(myToken),
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    },
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, since you want `Basic` authorization:

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(myToken)
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
request.clone({
     setHeaders: {
       'Authorization': `Basic ${myToken}`
     }
   });
```